# use kubernetes secret in another one

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

How can I use secret `X` key `my-key` in an other secret `Y` as `some-other-key`? Both secrets have other keys as well.

Rational: 
The mysql instance generates a secret containing the passwords for the users with keys `mysql-password` and `mysql-root-password`.
A custom resource `DbInstance` expects the name of a secret, which contains the keys `user` and `password`. (I use https://github.com/kloeckner-i/db-operator)
How can I put the value from one into the other?

Of course I can do it manually, by copying the encoded value from `kubectl get secret mysql-generated-secret` and paste it in `kubectl edit secret dbinstance-secret`.
Is there a better way? A reference in k8s if possible, or a nice automation. (I will find a way like `pwd=$(kubectl get secret -o yaml ... | yq .data.mysql-password | base64 -d) && helm update --set password=$pwd ...; unset pwd`, but is this the best way?)

similar:
[Using kubernetes secrets in a configmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57713006/using-kubernetes-secrets-in-a-configmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to automate this is by using an operator. listen on secret mysql-generated-secret, on creation or modification trigger -> create dbinstance-secret

Here is an operator who sync secrets between namespaces, you can use the same base code and modify it to your needs.

https://github.com/zakkg3/ClusterSecret

Comment: I agree this is the best way. Maybe a bit overkill for just using it about once. The python (yes!) code looks quite understandable. But from my experiance with shell-operator I doubt that I am already prepared for writing operators.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this as well and found a fairly easy solution using `yq`.

```
kubectl -n app-dev get secret database -o yaml | yq 'del(.metadata.creationTimestamp, .metadata.uid, .metadata.resourceVersion, .metadata.namespace)' | kubectl apply --namespace app-production -f -
```

We wrote it up as a blog post and a handy `just` command as well [Copying Kubernetes Secrets Between Namespaces](https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/copying-kubernetes-secrets-between-namespaces/)